# Visiting a URL in C

Tags: c, web-services, sockets, url

I know this is a very general question and believe me, I do appologize. However, I'm in a time crunch right now.

**What I need:**
I need to send data via a GET request to a web server.

Something like:

```
http://example.com/?info=%s
```

The website very well may be set up with cloudflare so direct IP access is not able to be used (ie gethostbynam).

I would need something as simple as a URL 'visitor'.

Comment: `libcurl` (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is the *de facto* standard, and is written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this **[example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html)** using [easy interface of **libcurl**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html).

Modify the URL string according to the parameter you need to pass to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by doukremnt and TheCodeArtist, use the following code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <curl/curl.h>

    int main(void)
    {
      CURL *curl;
      CURLcode res;

      curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
          fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                  curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```